# Popup shown twice when checkbox checked

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have it set up so that two checkboxes can not be checked at the same time, if they are then it will pop up an error and set the checkbox unchecked again. However currently it is popping up the message twice. How to fix this?

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
MsgBox "Must be sent separate."
CheckBox1.Value = False
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply need to change it too : the reason is it is running the check when switching checkbox1

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox2.Value = True And CheckBox1.Value = True Then
MsgBox "Must be sent separate."
CheckBox1.Value = False
End If
End Sub
```